# Permission for showing the device name to other users of the app

Tags: ios

Our application is using the `device name` as a name representing the user on other devices. Apple rejected our app because we are not asking for permission when the app is launched for the first time and gave reference to the [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW1).

Since I cannot find appropriate key for the specified problem I am wondering what the best way to handle it is. I am thinking of just displaying some `simple dialog` asking the user for permission but wonder if that will be sufficient. I will probably then need this setting available in the phone settings for the `App` like it is for example with Photos and Contacts but don't know how this should be achieved.

My question is if there is an appropriate key for this issue (like for example for Photos Library the key is `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`) or if not - how to handle it in the best way - some `AlertView` with the question + probably some way to store it in Settings but how should that be achieved ?

The code used for acquiring the device name is:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
```

Comment: There is nothing built-in for this. Anything you need to do for this is simply your own code.

Comment: Please added the code you use to get the device name to the question.  And why don't you ask the user name they want to use?  Because my device name is "Black iPhone".  I would want a different name if I was using your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple is pretty strict on requiring you to *ask* permissions, but pretty loose on *how* you ask it. As far as I know, even a simple, one-time `UIAlertView` is sufficient. Just store a value in `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`.